# How to use LINQ in java to query Azure Table

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table where the partition key is DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks that means the records are stored based on the partition key. I'm using java and would like to retrieve only the last record. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage/

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't explain how to retrieve the top 1 entry.

Comment: Ok, a couple other links then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340514/fastest-way-of-querying-for-latest-items-in-a-azure-table and http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-numbers-as-keys-in-windows-azure

Comment: thanks for links, but they are not talking about LINQ at all!

Comment: I'm sorry.  I must have not paid enough attention...

Comment: LINQ is not a Java concept -- it's a .NET concept so this question doesn't inherently make sense when framed as a LINQ issue. Storage itself has ways to query (like take count) and that is what you'll want to use in Java.

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft: I see, could you kindly share some piece of code in Java for retrieving only the first record from Azure Table?

Comment: Zhaoling provided the correct method below. If you check out the docs for that method I think you'll see what to do. If it's still not obvious could you maybe update your question with what you tried in Java so we can help you further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [setTakeCount](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/TableQuery.html#setTakeCount(java.lang.Integer))() in class TableQuery.

Comment: thanks, but could share more details on how to use it.

Comment: What additional questions do you have?