# Querying Azure storage between dates is very slow

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-table-storage

I have a scenario where I am trying to query azure storage for one week data. I am using a greater than today and less than 7th day to achieve this. I have 100 records a day on an average. This part of my code is very very slow. Is there any good option to query exactly to partition key values and get 7 days data?

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
var startDate = utcNow.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDate = utcNow.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var querySelectedDates = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
               TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, startDate),
               TableOperators.And,
               TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, endDate));

var tableQuery = new TableQuery<InteractionEntity>()
                    .Where(querySelectedDates);
return this.myTable.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery);
```

Comment: Does this SO post answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340514/fastest-way-of-querying-for-latest-items-in-a-azure-table

Comment: How about setting the partition key to the number of days since a specific date, as an integer - should make the range sorting and searching very fast as you will just be retrieving the contents of the last 7 partitions.   When you say slow, what kind of performance are you seeing - and is it the query that's doing it, or are you reading/storing some large data in there?