# Memory leak using AppendBlob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am downloading AppendBlob content using `DownloadText` method and I am experiencing a memory leak. Has it already happened to anybody? The code I use:

```
    private string[] GetBlobLines(CloudAppendBlob blob)
    {
        string text = "";
        try
        {
            lock (_blobContainerLock)
            {
                text = blob.DownloadText();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteToTable(MessageType.ERROR, "Error reading log lines: " + e.Message);
        }

        return text.Split('\n'); ;
    }


    public string GetLastLogRows(uint count)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var blob = _currentBlob;

        int lineCount = 0;
        int blobOffset = 0;

        while (lineCount < count)
        {
            var lines = GetBlobLines(blob);
            var blobLineCount = lines.Count();

            var i = blobLineCount - 1;
            while ((lineCount < count) && (i > -1))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(lines[i--]);
                lineCount++;
            }

            if (lineCount < count)
            {
                blobOffset++;
                blob = _blobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference($"{BLOB_PREFIX}{_currentBlobIdx - blobOffset}");

                if (!blob.Exists())
                    break;
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You probably have a programming error. Can you post your code. I guess you are missing a using.

Comment: I cannot find the DownloadText method with arguments in the microsoft documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudappendblob.aspx, is this an own extension method you have implemented? Or are you using an older version of the storage dlls?

Comment: No, all 4 params are null by default.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, each log record you stored is appended with a new-line character (\n). You leverage `GetLastLogRows` to retrieve the specific number log records in reverse order from your AppendBlob. In order to retrieve the specific log records, you need to download the whole AppendBlob file. At this point, memory leaks are a matter of time as the log content size increased. You could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to to check the detailed request when you invoking `CloudAppendBlob.DownloadText`, or use official tool [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to check the size of your AppendBlob file.

```html
if (lineCount < count)
{
    blobOffset++;
    blob = _blobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference($"{BLOB_PREFIX}{_currentBlobIdx - blobOffset}");

    if (!blob.Exists())
        break;
}
```

If I understand the above code correctly, you would check whether there has new AppendBlob file created when the number of the current log records is less than the desired parameter `count` of `GetLastLogRows`. And if it exists, you would download the new created AppendBlob file and combine the log records with the records from the previous AppendBlob file. At this point, the order of your retrieved log records are disrupted.

As I known, an append blob is optimized for append operations. I assumed that you could leverage [Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables) to store your logs. And you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340514/fastest-way-of-querying-for-latest-items-in-a-azure-table) to design PK and RK, then use [TableQuery.Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.take.aspx) to retrieve the latest records from your Table Storage. You could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/querying-tables-and-entities) for a better understanding of this method.